# Viewing local HTML files in iPad2

Tags: ipad, safari, mobile-safari

I am preparing an interactive PDF document that will be read in an iPad.I converted some of my flash contents into HTML files, that contain jQuery. I embedded those files into a PDF. I can see those files on a PC browser without a problem. But, iPad's browser Safari does not show local HTML files. Do you have any solution to see local HTML files on an iPad? I do not want to use Goodreader or etc to view such files.

Comment: It looks like you need Goodreader or a jail broken iPad. http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=970216

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a very small application wrapper around a `UIWebView`. Put your documents in its Resources folder and read from there.